# How to check if numbers precedes a more "verbal" string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given a `var dateText;` which outputs any single of this:

```
dateText = "12-5 November 17 May 1954";
dateText = "12 January 1976";
dateText = "12 22 March 1965";
```

And after doing:

```
for(var i = 0; i < dateText.length; i++) {
  d += dateText[i] + ' ';
}
var words = d.replace("–", " ").replace("-", " ").replace(",", " ").replace("/", " ").split(' ');
words = $.grep(words, function(n, i){
  return (n !== "" && n != null);
});
var array = words;
var newArray = array.filter(function(v){return v!==''});
for (const word of newArray) {
    if (months.has(word)) {
      localSpaceTime.Time.months.push(word);
    } else if (+word < 32) {
      localSpaceTime.Time.days.push(+word);
    } else if (+word < 2200) {
      localSpaceTime.Time.years.push(+word);
    } else if (/\w+/.test(word)) {
      localSpaceTime.Time.suffixes.push(word);
    }
}
```

Setting an array like:

```
    var localSpaceTime = {
      Title : "",
        Time : {
            days : [],
            months : [],
            years : [],
            suffixes : []
        }
    };
```

We'd end up like:

```
    var localSpaceTime = {
      Title : "",
        Time : {
            days : ["12", "5", "7"],
            months : ["november", "May"],
            years : ["1954"]
        }
    };
```

Which is fine but then the `database` wouldn't know any relation to which month 12, 5 or 7 belongs to.

My idea was:

> Go check if numbers precedes a verbal string (which would be the month) and if so do:

**Eng goal:**

```
Month: November
  Days: 12, 5
Month: May
  Days: 17
Year: 1954
```

I am aware that it is a bit of an `AI` teaching the script to think like humans but it is doable, just asking how would I do that as I'm out of ideas.

**UPDATE**

Another case would be:

```
dateText = "12-5 November 17 May 1954 CE";
```

Then the array would be:

```
var localSpaceTime = {
      Title : "",
        Time : {
            days : ["12", "5", "7"],
            months : ["november", "May"],
            years : ["1954"],
            suffix : ["CE"]
        }
    };
```

However our **End goal** would be:

```
Month: November
  Days: 12, 5
Month: May
  Days: 17
Year: 1954
Suffix: CE
```

The date could be also

```
1 May 1954 22-5 April 1970
```

or

```
1-19 May 1954
```

or

```
1-19, May 1954 21 April 1922
```

or

```
1-19, May 1954 CE 21 April 1922 BC
```

or

```
1-19,&nbsp;May&nbsp;1954&nbsp;CE&nbsp;21&nbsp;April&nbsp;1922&nbsp;BC
```

And I'd call it a day for these possibilities due to the results I am getting on my end, therefore parsing these would do the job.

Comment: What's your end goal? It seems like you're making a parsing problem harder than it needs to be.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have an array like: `Year -> Months -> Month -> Days`? It would be quite easy to build that up correctly and get the information out of it the way you want later

Comment: fire your algorithm in an answer pls, I will check it, i'm out of ideas

Comment: I'll work on it. May take a while. Been some time since I did Javascript. But an answer will come :)

Comment: @icecub ok man. Straight out of Stack! Sorry meant Compton due to your nick name :))

Comment: @MikeC check the updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we can assume the only non-numeric/whitespace/punctuation characters in the input will be month names, and the format is always as you describe, then the simplest solution may be to `split` on month names. For example:

```js
const input = '12-5 November 17 May 1954';
console.log(input.split(/\s+([a-z]+)\s+/i));
// => [ '12-5', 'November', '17', 'May', '1954' ]
```

Since we know that the result will always consist of one or more day-month pairs followed by the year, it's easy turn it into the result we want:

```js
const str = '12-5 November 17 May 1954';
const MATCH_MONTH_NAME = /\s+([a-z]+)\s+/i

function parseDates(input) {
  const parts = input.split(MATCH_MONTH_NAME);
  const result = { dates: [], year: null };

  while (parts.length >= 2) {
    const [ days, month ] = parts.splice(0, 2);
    result.dates.push({
      month,
      days: days.split(/\D+/),
    });
  }

  result.year = parts[0];
  return result;
}

console.log(parseDates('12-5 November 17 May 1954'));
console.log(parseDates('12 January 1976'));
console.log(parseDates('12 22 March 1965'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```

Comment: hang on, this looks very promising indeed

Comment: This is definitely a way better solution than what I was working on. So I suggest you use this :)

Comment: check the updated question for the case with a suffix

Comment: @downFast I understand, but what you want goes beyound my level of understanding. I would probably be able to do it, but my approach would be to split everything in all kinds of objects and rebuild a completely new array. It would work, but it would definitely be the wrong way to do it.

Comment: @icecub mmm i see

Comment: @downFast It wouldn't be hard to accommodate the additional characters, but it raises the question: What other formats are going to pop up?

Comment: @JordanRunning none for the moment, I'd stop the bot to only match and read these latest examples

Comment: @downFast I'm not at a computer now but if we can assume there's always a year then I *think* the code will still work if you change `>= 2` to `> 2`.

Comment: @JordanRunning still getting the suffix in the wrong place https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/pz3ce0o6/1485/

Comment: here it is another more complete solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/45562500/4518122 @JordanRunning