# How to split a string into corresponding objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given this:

```js
const MATCH_NAME = /\s+([a-z]+)\s+/i;

function parseDates(input) {
  const parts = input.split(MATCH_NAME);
  const result = {
    dates: [],
    year: null
  };

  while (parts.length > 2) {
    const [days, month, suffix] = parts.splice(0, 2);
    result.dates.push({
      month,
      days: days.split(/\D+/),
      suffix
    });
  }

  result.year = parts[0];
  return result;
}

console.log(parseDates('12-5 November 17 May 1954 CE'));
console.log(parseDates('1 January 1976 CE'));
console.log(parseDates('12 22 March 1965'));
```

The `year` obj ends up like `1976 CE` while `CE` should be in the `suffix`.

Trying to get to:

```
Month: November
  Days: 12, 5
Month: May
  Days: 17
Year: 1954
Suffix: CE
```

[jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/pz3ce0o6/1505/)

Comment: first of all, you need to define all possible date input combinations. Then match against those combinations.

Comment: My suggestion, use a pre-defined pattern for string

Comment: @Tschallacka the listed dates on here are the defined dates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555581/how-to-check-if-numbers-precedes-a-more-verbal-string

Comment: @Rajesh see comment above

Comment: For the third log, `console.log(parseDates('12 22 March 1965'));` , are you not going to put CE?

Comment: Link question does not have pattern `parseDates('12 22 March 1965');`

Comment: @samuel could do just as much as it couldn't, see the linked question with the date possible variations

Comment: @Rajesh what do you mean?

Comment: You know, you should try to write this homework yourself. @downfast

Comment: @downFast I think, the fastest way to solve this is to put the `possible errors` and the accepted strings so that we can parse it. Your pattern with console 1 and 2 are the same but for number 3 it's different. Perhaps, we could figure out the exact output if you'll do this.

Comment: @samuel the bot is giving me N numbers of possible dates, these are all listed on here and if any other would come up, i'll add to it but these are the data of hundreds of results so I'm taking them as the possibilities we'd have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555581/how-to-check-if-numbers-precedes-a-more-verbal-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding, your pattern is something like this:

- You have a list of values separated by spaces.
- Values can be numeric or alphabets.
- If Numeric,

  - If `<= 31`, its a day and should be pushed to days array.
  - Days can be separated by hyphens or space, if more than 1.
  - Else it is year.
- If alphabets,

  - If it is followed by year and length is less than 3(*assuming that suffix will be 2 digit and you can have a Date without date value(e.g.: "November 2007")*)
  - Else it is month.

**Note:** If my understanding is correct, then following solution will help you. If not, please share inconsistencies.

```js
function parseDates(input) {
  var parts = processHTMLString(input).split(/[-–,\/\s]/g);
  var result = [];
  var numRegex = /\d+/;
  var final = parts.reduce(function(temp, c) {
    if (numRegex.test(c)) {
      let num = parseInt(c);
      if (temp.year || (temp.month && num < 31)) {
        result.push(temp);
        temp = {};
      }
      temp.days = temp.days || []
      if (c.indexOf("-") >= 0) {
        temp.days = temp.days.concat(c.split("-"));
      } else if (num > 31)
        temp.year = c;
      else
        temp.days.push(c)
    } else if (c.length < 3 && temp.year) {
      temp.suffix = c
    } else {
      temp.month = c;
    }
    return temp;
  }, {});
  result.push(final);
  return result;
}

function processHTMLString(str) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = str;
  // This will process `&nbsp;` and any other such value.
  return div.textContent;
}

console.log(parseDates('12-5 November 2007 ce 17 May 1954 Ce'));
console.log(parseDates('1 January 1976 CE'));
console.log(parseDates('12 22 March 1965'));
```

Comment: we've added  `if (temp.year || (temp.month && num < 31) && temp.year > 0) {` in order to only push the whole object only if there is a month and we check in the else that the actual word is one of our months `} else if (months.has(c)) {
      temp.month = c;` given a set of our months `var months = new Set(["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]);` so this will also validate `May 4-10, 1988`